# Calculating data and generating rows in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to calculate row with columns using the following function:
row * EXP(columns)

Here is the data:

```
df<-read.table(text=" Time
2.5
2.1
2.2
3.1
4
-2
-3
-1",h=T)



df2= c(0.2, -0.1,   1,  2)
```

For example, 2.5*EXp(0.2); 2.5*EXP (-0.1), 2.5 *EXP(1), 2.5*EXP(2) 
The same for 2.1,2.2,.....-3.0.

This gives me the following table:

```
0.2 -0.1    1   2
3.053506895 9.603172812 893.9989236 18.47264025
2.564945792 6.686954761 301.3860014 15.51701781
2.687086068 7.320234183 395.5273835 16.25592342
3.78634855  16.52700973 4567.282501 22.90607391
4.885611033 37.31329406 52739.88682 29.5562244
-2.442805516    0.16370736  0.004354421 -14.7781122
-3.664208274    0.066237252 0.00028734  -22.1671683
-1.221402758    0.404607662 0.065988036 -7.389056099
```

I can do it based on Excel =(A3*EXP($D$2)), but I struggle to do it using R. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
t(sapply(df$Time, function(e){e*exp(df2)}))

          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  3.053507  2.2620935  6.795705  18.472640
[2,]  2.564946  1.9001586  5.708392  15.517018
[3,]  2.687086  1.9906423  5.980220  16.255923
[4,]  3.786349  2.8049960  8.426674  22.906074
[5,]  4.885611  3.6193497 10.873127  29.556224
[6,] -2.442806 -1.8096748 -5.436564 -14.778112
[7,] -3.664208 -2.7145123 -8.154845 -22.167168
[8,] -1.221403 -0.9048374 -2.718282  -7.389056
```

or:

```
Reduce(rbind,lapply(df$Time, function(e){e*exp(df2)}))

          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
init  3.053507  2.2620935  6.795705  18.472640
      2.564946  1.9001586  5.708392  15.517018
      2.687086  1.9906423  5.980220  16.255923
      3.786349  2.8049960  8.426674  22.906074
      4.885611  3.6193497 10.873127  29.556224
     -2.442806 -1.8096748 -5.436564 -14.778112
     -3.664208 -2.7145123 -8.154845 -22.167168
     -1.221403 -0.9048374 -2.718282  -7.389056
```

The `exp` function is vectorized:

```
exp(df2)
[1] 1.2214028 0.9048374 2.7182818 7.3890561
```

So the idea is to loop over the factor vector in front of your exponential, and to concatenate the output. You could do it old style with for loop and an empty table that you fill also. Here is what I proposed:

`lapply` is a loop which output a list :

```
lapply(df$Time, function(e){e*exp(df2)})
[[1]]
[1]  3.053507  2.262094  6.795705 18.472640

[[2]]
[1]  2.564946  1.900159  5.708392 15.517018

[[3]]
[1]  2.687086  1.990642  5.980220 16.255923

[[4]]
[1]  3.786349  2.804996  8.426674 22.906074

[[5]]
[1]  4.885611  3.619350 10.873127 29.556224

[[6]]
[1]  -2.442806  -1.809675  -5.436564 -14.778112

[[7]]
[1]  -3.664208  -2.714512  -8.154845 -22.167168

[[8]]
[1] -1.2214028 -0.9048374 -2.7182818 -7.3890561
```

To concatenate, you want to bind the rows together (with `rbind`) on all the list, and that is what `Reduce` do: apply a function on the list.

`sapply` is a version of lapply which attempt to give a nice output, but it was in the wrong sense, so I had to transpose it with `t()`.

Comment: `Reduce(rbind,lapply(df$Time, function(e){exp(df2-e)/(1+exp(df2-e))}))`

Answer (score 0):

How many EXP-values do you have? If it is only a handful this is a simple solution using `dplyr`, I have added an example for the first two columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate("0.2" = Time*exp(0.2),"-0.1" = Time*exp(-0.1)) %>%
  head()
```

Here a solution in base r for the first column.

```r
df["0.2"] <-df$Time*exp(0.2)
```

If you have a lot of EXP-values in your df2 you have to use a function from the `apply` family but with a handful this will work.

Comment: @user20100 in this case denis answer has the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at `outer()`. It's exactly what you want for this solution:

```
outer(df$Time, exp(df2))

          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  3.053507  2.2620935  6.795705  18.472640
[2,]  2.564946  1.9001586  5.708392  15.517018
[3,]  2.687086  1.9906423  5.980220  16.255923
[4,]  3.786349  2.8049960  8.426674  22.906074
[5,]  4.885611  3.6193497 10.873127  29.556224
[6,] -2.442806 -1.8096748 -5.436564 -14.778112
[7,] -3.664208 -2.7145123 -8.154845 -22.167168
[8,] -1.221403 -0.9048374 -2.718282  -7.389056
```

Note the default function for `outer` is multiplication. That is `outer(X, Y, FUN = '*')`. You can change the function to other stuff as well like `outer(X, Y, FUN = '+')` or any function you want.